# magento orders page load error

Tags: php, magento, orders

I have been scratching my head about this all day and still cant work it out. I have a local website and also a live version, i test extensions and changes on the local website and load them onto the live website if all ok.

I don't check my orders page of my local website often as its not live, but I have done this morning and found a error. I have renamed the error/local.xml.sample file and below is what it prints.

I only get this error when I click the orders page on the local host (not the live website). This mite be too general, and if it is I am sorry, just wondered if anyone can guild me into understanding what the problem is here?

```
There has been an error processing your request

Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/5/0/500_pro_b6...')
#1 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(1819): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'thumbnail')
#2 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/local/Amasty/Ogrid/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid/Renderer/Images.php(21): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->getThumbnailUrl()
#3 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column.php(128): Amasty_Ogrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid_Renderer_Images->render(Object(ITwebexperts_Itwebcommon_Model_Sales_Order))
#4 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml(161): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column->getRowField(Object(ITwebexperts_Itwebcommon_Model_Sales_Order))
#5 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/Oli/Desk...')
#6 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#7 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#8 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#9 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#12 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#13 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#14 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/Oli/Desk...')
#15 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#16 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#17 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#20 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#22 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#24 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#25 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Users/Oli/Desk...')
#26 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#27 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#34 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /Users/Oli/Desktop/Websites/CameraKings/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

Spoke to a friend and he suggested I add a placeholder to magento (System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Product Image Placeholder) and this has fixed the problem! Seems that maybe an image no longer existed.

Thought I would leave this here just incase others have the same problem